# Android Dialog Won't Resize (PhoneGap)

Tags: java, javascript, android, cordova

I have a `Dialog` with a custom view and it lets me set the x, y, width and height of the dialog, and that's all working.

I'm placing this `Dialog` over a `WebView` create by PhoneGap.

I sometimes need to reposition the dialog depending on what's going on in the `WebView`, so I created a function I could call from the JavaScript to resize it.

Here's how I am originally setting up the `Dialog`:

```
WindowManager.LayoutParams lp = new WindowManager.LayoutParams();
lp.x = this.dpToPixels(dialogDimensions.optInt("x")); 
lp.y = this.dpToPixels(dialogDimensions.optInt("y"));
lp.width = this.dpToPixels(dialogDimensions.optInt("width")); 
lp.height = this.dpToPixels(dialogDimensions.optInt("height"));
lp.gravity = Gravity.TOP | Gravity.LEFT;

// make it possible to click outside dialog
lp.flags = WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCH_MODAL | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_WATCH_OUTSIDE_TOUCH;

dialog.setContentView(main);
dialog.show();
dialog.getWindow().setAttributes(lp);
```

`dialogDimensions` is an `JSONObject` with the x, y, width, height parameters, and `dpToPixels()` converts the sizes to account for differences in pixel density (i.e. on the Nexus 10, 300px in the WebView is actually 600px on the tablet).

Here's my resize method:

```
public String resize(JSONObject dimensions) {
    dialogDimensions = dimensions;
    
    WindowManager.LayoutParams lp = dialog.getWindow().getAttributes();

    lp.x = this.dpToPixels(dialogDimensions.optInt("x")); 
    lp.y = this.dpToPixels(dialogDimensions.optInt("y"));
    lp.width = this.dpToPixels(dialogDimensions.optInt("width")); 
    lp.height = this.dpToPixels(dialogDimensions.optInt("height"));

    Log.i(LOG_TAG, dialog.getWindow().getAttributes().debug("Before Resize: "));
    dialog.getWindow().setAttributes(lp);
    Log.i(LOG_TAG, dialog.getWindow().getAttributes().debug("After Resize: "));

    return "";
}
```

The log messages are logging what I would expect, but the dialog doesn't do anything...

#### What I've Tried

I tried a `dialog.show()` then `dialog.show()` before, after and both before and after the `setAttributes()`.

I also tried to invalidate it, but I'm not sure I did it right... it was something I copied from a StackOverflow. Here's what I tried:

```
dialog.getCurrentFocus().invalidate();
dialog.getWindow().getCurrentFocus().invalidate();

main.invalidate(); // view passed into dialog.setContentView
```

I also tried a couple different ways of settings/getting the `LayoutParams` including creating a new set, copying, etc. Doesn't seem to make a difference. I even tried setting it to fill its parent and stuff, but no effect.

Any ideas how to get it to resize? Maybe it's not even an issue with the redraw?